# How to UPDATE by using REPLACE on different patterns within the same column value in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, sql-update, oracle12c

Here is a sample data of what I have in my `table FOO` -

```
        CREATE TABLE FOO 
           ( 
            NUMBERS VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
           );

           INSERT INTO FOO VALUES ('One,Five,Seven');
           INSERT INTO FOO VALUES ('One,Two,Three');
           INSERT INTO FOO VALUES ('Five,Five,Seven');
           INSERT INTO FOO VALUES ('Zero,Five,Seven');
       /*  .
           .
           .
          and so on.. */

SELECT * FROM FOO;
```

[image: the sample data]

I want to write an update statement to replace the text by their respective number. So the output should be like -

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. It's silly, but then so is the problem, so I don't feel too bad. It does work.

```
update foo
set numbers = (select listagg(decode(token,'Zero',0,'One',1,'Two',2,'Three',3,
                       'Four',4,'Five',5,'Six',6,'Seven',7,'Eight',8,'Nine',9)
                             , ',') within group (order by ord)
               from   json_table('["' || replace(numbers, ',', '","') || '"]',
                                 '$[*]'
                                 columns token varchar2 path '$', 
                                         ord for ordinality)
              )
;

select * from foo;

NUMBERS             
--------------------
1,5,7
1,2,3
5,5,7
0,5,7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an even sillier hack (still correct - it should work in Oracle 12.1 and higher). It's more interesting as an illustration of what's possible.

```
update /*+ with_plsql */ foo
  set numbers = (
    with
      function list_replace(str varchar2) return varchar2 as
        p integer := instr(str,',');
        function single_replace(token varchar2) return varchar2 as
        begin
          return case token when 'Zero'  then '0' when 'One'   then '1'
                            when 'Two'   then '2' when 'Three' then '3'
                            when 'Four'  then '4' when 'Five'  then '5'
                            when 'Six'   then '6' when 'Seven' then '7'
                            when 'Eight' then '8' when 'Nine'  then '9' end;
        end single_replace;
      begin
        return case p when 0 then single_replace(str)
                      else single_replace(substr(str,1,p-1)) || ',' ||
                           list_replace(substr(str,p+1)) end;
      end list_replace;
    select list_replace(numbers) from dual
  )
/
```

Comment: How did you come up with two responses? I could not find even one!!! Could you please explain the difference between the two answers?